# codeigniter, passing object to view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following in my codeigniter constructor:

```
$navbar= new stdClass(); 
$navbar->user_email = $this->user_email;
$navbar->vp = $this->vp;
```

When I try to access this in my index function:

```
public function index() {

     var_dump($this->navbar);
```

this works.

I now tried to pass $this->navbar to the view with:

```
$this->load->view('buyers/navbar', $this->navbardata);
```

In the view I have

```
<?php echo 'in nav ';var_dump($this->navbar); exit; ?>
```

I get :

```
Message: Undefined property: MY_Loader::$navbar
```

How can I make this work?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try like this

```
$data['navbar'] = $this->navbardata;
$this->load->view('buyers/navbar', $data);
```

and in your view try like

```
<?php echo 'in nav ';var_dump($navbar); exit; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create a controller like this

```
class Test extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data['topics'] = "Views Testing";
        $data['title'] = "Welcome To My Blog";
        $data['myData'] = array("name" => "John Doe", "email" => "johndoe2020@gmail.com", "designation" => "CodeIgniter Developer");

        $data['myObject'] = new MyClass("John Doe", "johndoe@gmail.com");

        $this->load->view("blogview", array($data, "MySelf" => new MyClass("Doe John", "doejohn460@gmail.com"), "developer" => "Life at CodeIgniter Academy"));

    }
}
class MyClass
{
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public function __construct($name, $email)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->email = $email;
    }
}
```

Now Create Your blogview.php File In views folder
And Add the following code to Access The Data Passed from Controllers

```
echo "<h3>Variables :</h3> ";
echo var_dump($title);
echo $title;
echo var_dump($topics);
echo $topics;
echo "<h3>Array :</h3> ";

echo var_dump($myData);
print_r($myData);
echo "<br><br>";
echo $myData['name'];
echo "<br>";
echo $myData['email'];
echo "<br>";
echo $myData['designation'];
echo "<br> <br>";
foreach ($myData as $data)
    {
        echo $data."<br>";
    }
echo "<h3>Object </h3>";

echo var_dump($myObject);
echo "<br>";
echo $myObject->name;
echo "<br>";
echo $myObject->email;
echo "<br><br>";

echo $MySelf->name;
echo "<br>";
echo $MySelf->email;
echo "<br><br>";
foreach($myObject as $Object)
{
    echo $Object."<br>";
}
echo "<h3>Array key:Value Pair</h3>";
echo $developer;
```

I hope this will help.