# codeigniter error log file only shows notice error but error msg not shows on screen

Tags: php, codeigniter, logging, error-handling, reference

I have been literally pulling my hair out with this one and its beginning to delay the rest of my project and it really is getting me down.

The main point is that it's only showing me a notice error and 404 Error in error log file not on screen and other notice errors shows on screen.

Why would codeigniter show errors in application/logs such as:

```
    ERROR - 2015-04-18 12:03:24 --> 404 Page Not Found --> uploaded_img

    ERROR - 2015-04-18 12:03:24 --> 404 Page Not Found --> images

    ERROR - 2015-04-18 12:03:24 --> 404 Page Not Found --> images

// Above all three errors are shows only when i visit home page of my website and I am not calling any type of images class

    ERROR - 2015-04-18 11:30:14 --> Severity: Notice  --> Trying to get property of non-object D:\wamp\www\mywebsite\application\views\product_detail.php 2

    ERROR - 2015-04-18 11:30:14 --> Severity: Notice  --> Trying to get property of non-object D:\wamp\www\mywebsite\application\views\product_detail.php 3

   ERROR - 2015-04-18 11:30:14 --> Severity: Notice  --> Trying to get property of non-object D:\wamp\www\mywebsite\application\views\product_detail.php 4

// Above all three errors are shown when i view product_detail.php page of my website.
```

My index.php is set at:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT)
```

and config :

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 1;
```

Here is my **Product controller** class code:

```
class Product extends Frontend_Controller{

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('product_m');
    $this->load->library('cart');
}

public function index($str){
    // fetch the article
    $this->data['product_info'] = $this->product_m->get_product_detail($str);

    // creating breadcrumb navigation path
    $this->data['main_category'] = $this->uri->segment(1);
    $this->data['sub_category'] = $this->uri->segment(2);
    $this->data['current_location'] = str_replace('-', ' ',str_replace('.html', '', $this->uri->segment(3))); 

    // load view
    $this->load->view('product_detail',$this->data);
}
```

}

when i do **var_dump($this->data['product_info'])**;

```
object(stdClass)[18]
  public 'id' => string '24' (length=2)
  public 'parent_category' => string 'sweets' (length=6)
  public 'child_category' => string 'chikki-sweets' (length=13)
  public 'product_url' => string 'chikki-bom-bom.html' (length=19)
  public 'product_name' => string 'Chikki Bom Bom' (length=14)
  public 'product_desc' => string '<span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 24px; font-family: Sans;">Chikki Bom Bom </span><span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 24px; font-family: Verdana;">Chikki</span><span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 24px; font-family: Sans;"> </span><span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 24px; font-family: 'Comic Sans MS';">Bom Bom.</span><div><span style="font-family: 'Comic Sans MS'; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 34.2857170104981px;"><br></span></div><div><pre><span style="font-f'... (length=1161)
  public 'product_sku' => string '123456789012' (length=12)
  public 'quantity' => string '23' (length=2)
  public 'price' => string '400.00' (length=6)
  public 'offer_price' => string '100.00' (length=6)
  public 'product_date' => string '2015-03-13' (length=10)
  public 'img_url_1' => string 'http://localhost/my_website/uploaded_img/chiki-boom-boom_1.png' (length=63)
  public 'img_url_2' => string 'http://localhost/my_website/uploaded_img/chikki_baadam_1.jpg' (length=61)
  public 'img_url_3' => string 'http://localhost/my_website/uploaded_img/white-rasbhari_1.jpg' (length=62)
  public 'img_url_4' => string 'http://localhost/my_website/uploaded_img/rasgulla_1.jpg' (length=56)
  public 'img_url_5' => null
```

Here is my **product_detail.php** code where its show's error:

```
$total_product = (int) $product_info->quantity; // line number 2
$mrp_price = (int) $product_info->price; // line number 3
$offer_price = (int) $product_info->offer_price; // line number 4
```

Here i did  **var_dump($product_info);** on product_detail.php page:

```
object(stdClass)[18]
 public 'id' => string '24' (length=2)
 public 'parent_category' => string 'sweets' (length=6)
 public 'child_category' => string 'chikki-sweets' (length=13)
 public 'product_url' => string 'chikki-bom-bom.html' (length=19)
 public 'product_name' => string 'Chikki Bom Bom' (length=14)
 public 'product_desc' => string '<span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 24px; font-family: Sans;">Chikki Bom Bom </span><span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 24px; font-family: Verdana;">Chikki</span><span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 24px; font-family: Sans;"> </span><span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 24px; font-family: 'Comic Sans MS';">Bom Bom.</span><div><span style="font-family: 'Comic Sans MS'; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 34.2857170104981px;"><br></span></div><div><pre><span style="font-f'... (length=1161)
 public 'product_sku' => string '123456789012' (length=12)
 public 'quantity' => string '23' (length=2)
 public 'price' => string '400.00' (length=6)
 public 'offer_price' => string '100.00' (length=6)
 public 'product_date' => string '2015-03-13' (length=10)
 public 'img_url_1' => string 'http://localhost/my_website/uploaded_img/chiki-boom-boom_1.png' (length=63)
 public 'img_url_2' => string 'http://localhost/my_website/uploaded_img/chikki_baadam_1.jpg' (length=61)
 public 'img_url_3' => string 'http://localhost/my_website/uploaded_img/white-rasbhari_1.jpg' (length=62)
 public 'img_url_4' => string 'http://localhost/my_website/uploaded_img/rasgulla_1.jpg' (length=56)
 public 'img_url_5' => null
```

What should i do to remove these error?

Comment: you better post some code from product_detail.php

Comment: Now I added code, please check it once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `semi colon` is a syntax error. Set

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 0;
```

Comment: no its not fetching associative array brother its returning object..wait i am posting snaps shot of var_dump($this->data['product_info']);

Comment: brother i posted result of var_dump($this->data['product_info']); please check it now

Comment: @shawn_parker checkout following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909830/codeigniter-passing-object-to-view

Comment: no its not working. brother remember that error not shows on screen but if remove semicolon from any line its show error on screen.

Comment: i can't see the solution of this problem.. i am searching solution from last 5 hours

Comment: @shawn_parker If it's causing you so much trouble why don't you try  returning associative array instead of object

Comment: brother check it once again. i did var_dump() on product_detail.php page.

Comment: You said error is not displayed on the screen. Can you try doing a var_dump of $total_product after you assign it the value. Removing semicolon is a syntax error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75619/discussion-between-shawn-parker-and-adnan-kamili).

Answer (score 0):

set

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

and make sure ENVIRONMENT is set in your index.php file as:

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
```

which sets the error_reporting to E_ALL.

Comment: codeigniter showing me all php errors but it not shows only these error recroded in error log file...